# SSIS(VS 2012) Issue with VB script compounent

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I am facing an issue in SSIS. I just upgraded my project from VS 2005 to VS 2012 and all of my packages were upgraded at the same time.
All of them work well, except the one where I use script task to check if a file exists in a folder before working on the data from the flat file.

Since this upgrade, when I launch package with this script task:

- If the file is present in the folder, it works well.
- If the file is missing, it crashes just after the "else" clause on :
  Dts.Events.FireError(0, "FlatFile", "Error loading '" + filepath + "', flat file not found", String.Empty, 0) with the following error message:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()**

And then it crashes on the end sub with the  following error message:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()**

If I disable the Dts.Events.FireError I still got the same error on the end sub

Here is my code(Visual Basic 2012):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim filepath As String
        filepath = "\\localhost\MYPATH"

            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filepath) Then
        If FileLen(filepath) > 0 Then
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
        Else
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "FlatFile", "Error loading '" + filepath + "', flat file not found", String.Empty, 0)
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure

        End If
    Else
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "FlatFile", "Error loading '" + filepath + "', flat file not found", String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Try moving the file size check into an in inner if statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems to work, I will try on my other package today aswell and confirm...

Answer (score 2):

I expect the issue is that you are not providing a return status for the subroutine

```
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filepath) And FileLen(filepath) > 0 Then
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    Else
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "FlatFile", "Error loading '" + filepath + "', flat file not found", String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    End If
```

### Edit

Expectations are one thing but actually debugging is another. I set a break point at the step where you assigned filepath. The root problem is that the `FileLen` operation is trying to check the size of a file that doesn't exist. Here you can see that a FileNotFoundException is thrown and unhandled.

[image]

Comment: I already tried with this, but it doesn't change anything... I got the issue on the "fireerror" event and when I debug I directly get the error message on the FireError line...

Comment: Updated with your root cause

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am back with this issue, it's still not working I tried to put an inner if as proposed, but it's still not working I got the same error on the DTS.Events.FireError line I also tried to remove the dts.events.fireerror but it's also not working - I got the same error at the "End Class" line. I also try to add a scriptresults.failure but no success. I updated my code with the new one, do you got any more idea???